# I cannot send a message using the Twilio API in Kotlin, as an error shows and crashes my app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, twilio, twilio-api

I have been trying to make my app send me SMS messages for a while now, but have not been able to figure anything out. I have been trying to use Twilio's 2 official tutorials for sending SMS messages in Kotlin. This is my code:

```kotlin
Twilio.init("mytwiliosid", "mytwilioauth")

        val message = Message.creator(
                PhoneNumber("mynumber"),
                PhoneNumber("twilionumber"),
                "Hello from Starfruit!"
        ).create()

        print(message.sid)
```

I have this on my OnCreate function to test. However, whenever I try to run my app, it crashes. My code runs fine if I take this out, but whenever I have it in my app, it immediately crashes when opened, and shows this error message in LogCat:

```
2020-10-21 22:54:05.302 7120-7120/com.gradient.starfruit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gradient.starfruit, PID: 7120
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:172)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
        at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:58)
        at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:102)
        at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:122)
        at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
        at com.gradient.starfruit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

I honestly don't really understand the error message, but I am fairly certain my Message.creator is causing it. If anyone knows what I can do to fix this error, or what I should do instead of what I'm doing now to send a message in Kotlin, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: what version Android sdk are you using?

Comment: @A-Developer-Has-No-Name I'm using version 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly what I was originally making, but I found a way to relatively simply send a message from an android app.

```kotlin
val smsManager: SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("+19999999999", null, "Message goes here!", null, null);
```

This will make the phone itself text any number. You'll also need send_sms permissions for this, so you should have a `<uses-permission>` for that in your manifest file, as well as this code in your MainActivity file to ask for the permission.

```kotlin
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this@MainActivity, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS), 1)
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS), 1)
            }
        }
```